# Does the article in LaTeX support sections only three levels deep?

Tags: latex, org-mode

I'm using Emacs for writing my XeLaTeX documents.

[image]

The formatting and indentation in Emacs is virtual so it is easier for the eyes but  in the saved file everything aligns to the left, like so:

```
* First
** Second
*** Third
```

I've noticed however that the fourth level section is more like a paragraph and it is indented in the PDF. Does the article only support three level deep sections? Is there a way to make that paragraph-like heading align to the left as well and make it bold at least? I don't think I ever go deeper than four levels, but three is quite limiting.

[image]

Comment: If you look into your tex file, you will see that your forth level is not a heading but an enumerate environment

Comment: I realized that. So there is no way to have a fourth level heading then.

Comment: Of course there is, that is what `\paragraph{}` is made for

Answer (score 1):

The article document class supports more than three levels of headings, although the 4th is unnumbered by default, you'll just have to use `\paragraph{...}` and not an enumerate environment, like in your code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\subsection{title}

\subsubsection{title}

\paragraph{title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your time. I updated my post with the output I see in the TEX file. Emacs generates both a PDF and a TEX file when exporting. I suppose I need to tell Emacs somehow to use `paragraph{}` instead of `\begin{enumerate}` Am I right?

Comment: I managed to get Emacs to output `\paragraph{title}` however the content that comes after `\paragraph{title}` is also on the same line with the `\paragraph{title}`, even though there is one line space between the content and the `\paragraph{title}
` thing in the source code. I posted a new image so you can see what I'm talking about.